# Laravel - Checking if slug field is empty, if it is then to do something automatically

Tags: laravel

I want to check if the user inputted any value in my slug field since I want to give user opportunity to do it dynamically. If the field is empty I want to generate it automatically based on the title of the post. I have tried something like this:

```
$title = $request->title;

    if(empty($slug)){
        $slug = Str::slug($title);
    } else {
        $slug = Str::slug($request->slug);
    }
```

but now I am not sure how to use it. I have tried to `return $slug;` but it does not work:

```
 Post::create([
            'user_id' => auth()->user()->id,
            'category_id' => $request->category_id,
            'title' => $title,
            'slug' => $slug,
```

If someone knows different approach please help :)
Thanks!

**SOLVED**
This part of code will help you guys if you ever encounter this "issue" :)

```
$slug = Str::slug($request->input('slug'));

if (empty($slug)) {
    $slug = Str::slug($request->input('title');
}

Post::create([...]);
```

Comment: Can you share with us where is all of this code located? Is the slug generator a separate function, is it in the same controller, where is the second code block located?

Comment: you can try https://github.com/spatie/laravel-sluggable as slug should be uniquee you need to do manually checks to avoid all you can use this

Comment: @KamleshPaul wanna do it manually :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```php
$slug = $request->input('slug');

if (!isset($slug)) {
    $slug = Str::slug($request->input('title'));
}

Post::create([...]);
```

Comment: Thank you for this code I will just edit it a little bit since it does not work in this form :)

Comment: Yeah I missed a closing bracket, apologies!

Comment: also this part !isset did not work for me but empty did :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like that,

```
      //validate the data before 
    Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'title' => '',//, check the rules avalaible here https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#available-validation-rules
        'slug' => '',
    ])->validate();//If validation fails, the user will automatically be redirected or, in the case of an AJAX request, a JSON response will be returned:
    //get the slug value or the title if the slug is not present
    $slug = $request->input('slug', $request->input('title'));
    Post::create([
        'user_id' => auth()->user()->id,
        'category_id' => $request->category_id,
        'title' => $title,
        'slug' => $slug,
    ]);
```

Cordially

Comment: will try it :) I am using validations from model and request :) The controller is a bit cleaner then

Comment: Sure, the point here is to provide a functional code